# Why implode() can accept its parameters in either order, explode() cannot.?

Tags: php

Although `implode()` can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order, `explode()` cannot. Why?

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

is similar to

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode( $array,",");
```

Why?

Comment: Because it was originally written that way, testing the datatype of the first argument to see whether it is an array or a string.... you'll note that it can also accept its arguments as `implode ( array $pieces )` or as `implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )` to allow for the default glue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#refsect1-function.implode-description) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#refsect1-function.explode-parameters) documentation, they only said it's historical reason.

This is what found in [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-historical-reasons-for-PHPs-implode-being-able-to-accept-its-arguments-in-either-order-but-explode-not-being-able-to). Also the reason sounds promising!!

> Part of the reason, I guess, is that both parameters of explode are
>   strings, thus it would be difficult to tell which is the delimiter and
>   which is the original string if they're swapped. Implode, however,
>   takes a string (glue) and an array (pieces) as its parameters. It's at
>   least easy to tell them apart.
>
> The 'historical reason' might refer to an API design guideline change,
>   where it was decided that 'smaller' parameters (needle, glue) should
>   be before 'bigger' parameters (haystack, pieces). Implode might have
>   used the reverse order before that.

Comment: This behavior has been changed in PHP 8. Now `implode()` only accepts glue as 1st parameter and pieces as 2nd.