# Uncaught TypeError: join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given / PHP8 data for highcharts

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts, php-8

My webhost changed the PHP Version from PHP7.4 to PHP8.
Now my Highcharts are not shown anymore and I got an error message depending to the Highcharts series data.

The data for the chart comes from a mysql database.

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: join(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in testchart.php:64
Stack trace:
\#0 testchart.php(64): join(Array, ',')
\#1 {main}
thrown in testchart.php on line 64
```

My call of `join()`:

```
data: [<?php echo join($tempA24, ',') ?>],
```

This is the array with the database values:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    [0] => float(1667131200000)[1] => float(21)
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    [0] => float(1667134800000)[1] => float(22)
  }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the answer: The error is very clear. It's worth the effort to read errors *slow*. Rubber ducky that stuff (in your head): "It says first must be an array, and i'm doing that, i'm inputting a.... huh, string?"

Comment: A contentious contributor might add a modern answer to [Why implode() can accept its parameters in either order, explode() cannot.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34355231/2943403)

Comment: Related: [Error Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55372280/2943403)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for `join` is the other way round - it should be `join($separator, $array)`

Or, in your case: `join(',', $tempA24);`

As for the reason it used to work - there *was* a legacy signature taking the arguments the other way around. However, this was deprecated in PHP 7.4, and has now been removed in PHP 8.0

[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) (`join` is a direct alias of `implode`):

> `implode(string $separator, array $array): string`
>
> Legacy signature (deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0, **removed as of PHP 8.0.0**):
> `implode(array $array, string $separator): string`